# Reading File from another Package in Java using getResourceAsStream()

Tags: java, classloader, readfile

I am trying to read a file called "numbers.txt" which is filled with int numbers (one int per line, no empty lines). I want to put the numbers into an array and return this array (method `readIntsFromFile`). Unfoutnetly the File does not get found, so the `InputStream cls` returns null. If I put the file "numbers.txt" into the same folder as the Class `ReadFileInput` it works but I do not know why it does not work if I put the "numbers.txt" file into the resources folder. I thought `getResourceAsStream()` can get it there? The main just creates a new class Object and calls the class function with the parameter "numbers.txt" and saves the result in an array.

Here is the Class with the method `readIntsFromFile`:

```
package impl;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ReadFileInput {

    public int[] readIntsFromFile(String path) {
        ArrayList<Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            InputStream cls = ReadFileInput.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
            System.out.println("Get Resources as Stream: " + cls);
         
            //Put cls in ArrayList
        
            }
            cls.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        int[] arr = arrList.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
        System.out.println(arr);
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Do you know how it could work?

All the best!

Comment: The problem is due to an incorrect path. You need to show the value for parameter `path` that you pass to method `readIntsFromFile` as well as the location of directory `resources` relative to directory `impl`.

Comment: Note that putting a resource in the same package as a class is a good practice.  Putting a resource in the root package is a bad practice, because it risks collision with other applications/libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string value you pass to `SomeClass.class.getResource()` (as well as `getResourceAsStream`, of course) has two 'modes'.

1. It looks 'relative to the package of `SomeClass`', which means, effectively, if you ask for e.g. `"img/load.png"`, and `SomeClass` is in the package `com.foo`, you're really asking for `"/com/foo/img/load.png"` - this is **relative mode**.
2. You want to go into absolute mode: You want the 'classpath source' that provided the `SomeClass.class` file that the JVM used to load the code for SomeClass, and then look in that same place for, say, `/img/load.png` from there. In other words, if `SomeClass`'s code was obtained by loading the bytecode from jar file entry `/com/foo/SomeClass.class` in jarfile `myapp.jar`, you want the data obtained by loading the jar file entry `/img/load.png` from jarfile `myapp.jar`. You can do that - simply start with a slash.

Given that your numbers.txt file appears to be in the 'root' of `resources`, that would strongly suggest the string you pass to `.getResourceAsStream()` should be `"/numbers.txt"`. Note the leading slash.

NB: It's not *quite* a path. `..` and such do not work. Weirdly, `com.foo.numbers.txt` would, if the jar file contains `/com/foo/numbers.txt`.